# How to change QLineEdit spacing between text and its edge

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

The code below creates a single QLineEdit with its font size set to 9.
I would like to make sure there is no spacing between the text and the edge of the LineEdit.

What attribute controls the mentioned spacing?

[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
app = QApplication(list())
line = QLineEdit()
font = line.font()
font.setPointSize(9)
line.setFont(font)
line.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that space does not appear is that the height of the QLineEdit is fixed, and to calculate that height QFontMetrics should be used:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(list())
line = QLineEdit()

font = line.font()
font.setPointSize(9)
line.setFont(font)

fm = QFontMetrics(line.font())
line.setFixedHeight(fm.height())

line.show()
app.exec_()
```